# When did this "Great Siege" that the orcs talk about in this dialog happen?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

An extract from the Two Towers - The Choices of Master Samwise

> At this point Sam began to listen more attentively and pressed his ear
>   against the stone.
>
> 'Who cut the cords she'd put round him, Shagrat? Same one as cut the
>   web. Didn't you see that? And who stuck a pin into Her Ladyship? Same
>   one, I reckon. And where is he? Where is he, Shagrat? '
>
> Shagrat made no reply.
>
> `You may well put your thinking cap on, if you've got one. It's no
>   laughing matter. No one, no one has ever stuck a pin in Shelob before,
>   as you should know well enough. There's no grief in that; but
>   think-there's someone loose hereabouts as is more dangerous than any
>   other damned rebel that ever walked since the **bad old times, since the
>   Great Siege**. Something has slipped.'

What is this "Great Siege" the two orcs are talking about?

Comment: Sounds like the Siege of Barad-dur in the War of the Last Alliance, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: That's the only siege that's occurred in Mordor, as far as I can remember.

Comment: If they refer to the Siege of Barad-Dur, it would mean either that Gorbag and Shagrat are very old or that they are taught a fairly extensive history.  Either would be at odds with the "conventional" view of orcs.  Gorbag and Shagrat being thousands of years old means their typical lives would have been far less violently precarious than what we see in LotR.  The history lessons would mean strong communication, which is quite different from the description of orcs as poor communicators.  Food for thought...

Comment: @La-comadreja that's an interesting speculation. I'll ask a different question on the topic. There is already a question asked about "how much do the Orcs live" and the answer is definitely not "they are immortal". Still I see little canon sources in there.

Comment: @La-comadreja I would say they wouldn't necessarily have to be "taught history" to know about such a pivotal event from their past. An event that big and impactful seeps into the culture and becomes part of the mythology you grow up with without having to be specifically taught it, perhaps comparable with the Great Plague or the Sack of Rome in Western culture.

Comment: Looking at the dialog, I think it's readily apparent that orcs aren't *quite* as dumb and non-communicating as the movies tend to picture them. That's not guttural grunts and "kill, kill, kill" chants...

Comment: Note that 3000 years is roughly as old as the oldest battle I've heard of, the fall of Troy (~1200 BC).

Comment: @RemcoGerlich yes.  And when was the last time you made a comparison to something that happened 3,000 years ago?  And when you did, how couldn't you attribute your doing so to the extensive information sharing you received and the complicated culture you inherited?

Comment: @La-comadreja: Yesterday, actually :-)  Quoted the Odyssey line about it being a wise child that knows its own father.  Also note that Shagrat and Gorbag aren't ordinary Orcs, but troop leaders - officers, IOW - and so have probably been to Sauron's equivalent of Sandhurst/West Point.

Comment: @La-comadreja the Trojan horse is still referenced to this day (indeed a type of computer virus is named after it)

Comment: @La-comadreja There is the very significant difference that despite the 3,000-year gap, several of the entities (I hesitate to say ‘people’) at the top of Gorbag and Shagrat’s chain of command—namely Sauron himself and the Ringwraiths, if not others—were _actually there at the Great Siege they're talking about_. Most 10-year-olds in our world have heard of Odysseus and Trojan horses, even though it's basically irrelevant to our lives, so it's hardly surprising that even Orcs would know of such a vital event in their own lord general’s history.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## The Siege Of Barad-Dúr

The siege that ended the War of the Last Alliance, and the Second Age, was called **The Great Siege** and is also explicitly referenced as such by Tolkien:

> "*the Second Age ends with the Last Alliance (of Elves and Men) and **the great siege of Mordor***"
>
> <sub>*Letter 131*</sub>

I would say it's safe to conclude that this is the Great Siege of old that is being spoken about. The siege started in *SA 3434* and ended in *SA 3441* along with the Second Age. This conversation was in *TA 3019*, meaning the siege was 3026 years before.

Comment: So this happened like several thousand years ago?

Comment: @vap78: yes, the siege basically ended when Gil-galad and Isildur's father defeated Sauron and the ring was cut from Sauron's finger.

Comment: @vap78 - about 3,000 years.

Answer (score 28):

Mordor was besieged for 7 years during [the Last Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordor#The_Last_Alliance_and_Third_Age). It was after this that the tower of Cirith Ungol was built by the men of the west to guard Mordor.

> As he gazed at it suddenly Sam understood, almost with a shock, that this stronghold had been built not to keep enemies out of Mordor, but to keep them in. It was indeed one of the works of Gondor long ago, an eastern outpost of the defences of Ithilien, made when, after the Last Alliance, Men of Westernesse kept watch on the evil land of Sauron where his creatures still lurked.
>
> <sup>The Return of the King: The Tower of Cirith Ungol</sup>